# Trigger to sum value of column of all rows and store in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in oracle.

`invoice(id_invoice, description, price)`

`product_invoice(id,id_invoice, description, price, quantity, final_price)`

I want to do the the "sum" of the column of "final_price" with all the rows with the same "id_invoice" and store it in the table invoice.
I'm trying using triggers but not working.
Here's my trigger

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER updateukupno AFTER insert ON stavkaotpremnice FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE invoice a
SET a.price = 
    (SELECT SUM(final_price) 
       FROM product_invoice
      WHERE id_invoice = a.id_invoice)
 WHERE a.id_invoice = :NEW.id_invoice;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of logic is usually expressed incrementally:

```
UPDATE invoice i
    SET price = price + coalesce(:new.final_price, 0)) 
    WHERE i.id_invoice = :NEW.id_invoice;
```